# Stop Explorer from Starting on Logon

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, gui

I am looking to create a custom GUI for Windows 7/8 to replace Windows Explorer (explorer.exe), but it doesn't seem possible to stop Windows Explorer from starting without the use of a .bat file and scheduling a task to execute said batch file on logon.

I was thinking that I could probably remove/rename `C:/Windows/explorer.exe`, but this could potentially destabilize Windows and I have no wish for such a thing to happen.

I've seen methods to change the Windows default shell in the registry, but I'm unsure if these registry tweaks work with Windows 7/8.

How can I stop Windows Explorer from starting on logon ***without the use of a batch file***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the Windows Explror as Shell by modifying the value `Shell` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and pointing to a custom shell.